# how to change the linewidth of point using the geom_point()?

Tags: r

I used the `geom_point(data,aes(x=...,y=...))+geom_point(shape=1)` to plot. The question is that I want to change the line width of the hollow.  `circle.size` is used to change the diameters and `fill` is used to change the colors. I didn't find parameters to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stroke` inside `geom_point`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4, stroke = 3)
```

[image]